# ASP NET C# Button backcolor cannot be printed

Tags: asp.net, button, printing, backcolor

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Next View" OnClick="goToSecondView_Click" BackColor="Red"/>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Go Back" OnClick="goToFirstView_Click"  BackColor="Blue" />
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Few simple lines of code that shows 2 options of buttons: One is red, one is blue. When I want to print the website (using browser's print menu), the buttons always appear white on the print preview, even when I print them. Anyone know how can I print the button backcolor? I tried on IE and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MS, To resolve this behavior, turn on the Print background colors and images option in Internet Explorer. To do this, follow these steps: 1.On the Tools menu, click Internet Options, and then click the Advanced tab.
2.In the Settings box, under Printing, click to select the Print background colors and images check box, and then click OK.

Comment: Excellent! Really didn't expect it because of a print setting. I thought that I needed to add or change something on my code. Thank you very much Dean. It works now.